# Unable to create multiple html buttons using same class with different url

Tags: html

We are trying to create multiple buttons with different url.. by using below code..

However when trying to add multiple body tags its not accepting multiple buttons and only one button is getting displayed in the final output. Is there anything i am missing

```html
    <head> 
        <style> 
            body { 
                padding: 0; 
                margin: 0; 
            } 
    
            a { 
                position: absolute; 
                top: 20%; 
                left: 80%; 
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
                width: 80px; 
                height: 20px; 
                color: white; 
                text-decoration: none; 
                text-align: center; 
                padding-top: 10px; 
                font-size: 13px; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                background: orange; 
            } 
    
            a::before { 
                content: ""; 
                position: absolute; 
                width: 0; 
                height: 0; 
                left: 0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                border-style: solid; 
                border-color: #b34700; 
                border-width: 80px 100px; 
                z-index: -1; 
                transform: rotate(360deg); 
                transition: 1s; 
                transform-origin: left; 
            } 
    
            a:hover::before { 
                border-color: #ffc87c; 
                transform: rotate(60deg); 
            } 
        </style> 
    </head> 
    
    <body> 
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Home </a> <br>
        <p> AAAAAAAAAAAAA </p>
    </body>  
    
    <body> 
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Home </a> <br>
        <p> AAAAAAAAAAAAA </p>
    </body>
```

but when i add an extra button its not adding the button and only one button is getting displayed

Is something i am missing in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id dont know why you use two body tag! its should be one body tag, but there is two button in page in the same position you can see another one by add some margin to one of them!

in your code

```html
 <head> 
        <style> 
            body { 
                padding: 0; 
                margin: 0; 
            } 
    
            a { 
                position: absolute; 
                top: 20%; 
                left: 80%; 
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
                width: 80px; 
                height: 20px; 
                color: white; 
                text-decoration: none; 
                text-align: center; 
                padding-top: 10px; 
                font-size: 13px; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                background: orange; 
            } 
    
            a::before { 
                content: ""; 
                position: absolute; 
                width: 0; 
                height: 0; 
                left: 0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                border-style: solid; 
                border-color: #b34700; 
                border-width: 80px 100px; 
                z-index: -1; 
                transform: rotate(360deg); 
                transition: 1s; 
                transform-origin: left; 
            } 
    
            a:hover::before { 
                border-color: #ffc87c; 
                transform: rotate(60deg); 
            } 
        </style> 
    </head> 
    
    <body> 
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="margin-top:50px">Home </a> <br>
        <p> AAAAAAAAAAAAA </p>
    </body>  
    
    <body> 
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Home </a> <br>
        <p> AAAAAAAAAAAAA </p>
    </body>
```

clean code:

```html
 <head> 
        <style> 
            body { 
                padding: 0; 
                margin: 0; 
            } 
    
            a { 
                position: absolute; 
                top: 20%; 
                left: 80%; 
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
                width: 80px; 
                height: 20px; 
                color: white; 
                text-decoration: none; 
                text-align: center; 
                padding-top: 10px; 
                font-size: 13px; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                background: orange; 
            } 
    
            a::before { 
                content: ""; 
                position: absolute; 
                width: 0; 
                height: 0; 
                left: 0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                border-style: solid; 
                border-color: #b34700; 
                border-width: 80px 100px; 
                z-index: -1; 
                transform: rotate(360deg); 
                transition: 1s; 
                transform-origin: left; 
            } 
    
            a:hover::before { 
                border-color: #ffc87c; 
                transform: rotate(60deg); 
            } 
            .two{margin-top:50px;
           }
        </style> 
    </head> 
    
    <body> 
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Home </a> <br>
        <p> AAAAAAAAAAAAA </p>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="two">Home </a> <br>
        <p> AAAAAAAAAAAAA </p>
    </body>
```

Comment: can we add side by side button instead of in new line ?

Comment: is there any possibility to add side by side

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one *body* tag in HTML. It will not give an error but it won't consider any styling of the *body* tags except for the first one.

Comment: Cant we add multiple buttons any other way.. I am trying to add two buttons . Is there a way i can add it